# Function overloading two functions only differ by a default parameter

Tags: function, oop, overloading

Two methods with the same name and have 2 same parameters and one of the methods has an extra optional(default) parameter.

So when I called a method as shown in the image why method with an optional parameter not called?

Why answer is **ab** not **abc**?

[image]

```
func call(x:String, y:String, z:String! = "c") -> String{
    //z parameater is optional
    print("3 parameater!")
    return x+y+z;
}

func call(x:String, y:String) -> String{
    print("2 parameater!")
    return x+y;
}

call(x: "a", y: "b")
```

Comment: Post code, not screenshots of code.

Comment: What language is that? .overload resolution is based on rules. These defer between different languages.

Answer (score 1):

Because when you omit the optional parameter, the method without it is a better match for the call.
The scenario you are describing makes no sense - if there's already an overload with the first two parameters, the third one should not be optional.

Overload resolution rules differ between languages/frameworks - but this is kind of an obvious choice and I seriously doubt any compiler would ever pick the method with an extra optional parameter.
In fact, I'm surprised this even compiles (I've checked an equivalent c# code, and it does compile, without even a warning)